# Why Cloud Endpoint does not trace my API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, trace

I setup a cloud endpoint. 
I try to fire some 50 qps request and check the Stackdriver tracing. 
Nothing happened.

I found the ESP proxy of CloudEndpoint attach the following headers:

```
X-Real-Ip: 
X-Forwarded-For: 
X-Google-Real-Ip: 
X-Ms-Request-Source-Ikey: 
X-Endpoint-Api-Project-Id: 
X-Cloud-Trace-Context:
```

My server get the request and response with my new headers.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: I sort it out. Note that the GKE k8s permission for `Stackdriver Trace`  need to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to clarify:

- Is the Stackdriver Trace API enabled on your GCP Project? You can check this by navigating to `APIs and Services` (in the hamburger menu on Google Cloud console) --> `Library` --> `Stackdriver Trace Api`
- Are you using OpenAPI, gRPC, or Frameworks?
- What platform are you using? GAE standard, GAE Flex, GKE, GCE?

Also note that Endpoints does provide public documentation for tracing: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/tracing